# mysql run query but dont show results

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table with large number of rows (10m)

From the mysql client, I want to run a query but not print results. This is because even though the query runs in 15 seconds, printing the results on to console takes many minutes.

How can I achieve this?

EDIT: My query is the following:

```
select user_id, count(*) as ct from user_geo_loc group by user_id, lat, lng;
```

EDIT 2: At the end of the execution, the mysql client prints the following

```
9950710 rows in set (9.31 sec)
```

I want to find out this time but not print the results (which takes 15 minutes)

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT NULL FROM your_table;` ?

Comment: Do you want all the results or do you not? If not, add a "limit" to your query. If yes - wait.

Comment: ?? So don't run the query ??

Comment: @fancyPants, distinct null seems to alter the running time of the original query.

Comment: @TJ- limit will stop the query execution as soon as the limit as reached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When on Linux, you could redirect the output to `/dev/null` to prevent the output. Like this:

```
mysql -u username -p database -e "SELECT * FROM table" > /dev/null
```

On Windows the equivalent would be:

```
mysql -u username -p database -e "SELECT * FROM table" > NUL
```

Please note: The only thing printed on the console will be errors, to prevent this, you would have to redirect `stderr` to `stdout` by adding `2>&1` to the end (Linux)

Comment: Thanks. I just added the unix time command to measure the time

Comment: How to print the execution time though?

Answer (score 1):

In console, you may redirect output into the null device:

```
$ mysql -uUSER -pPASSWORD -e"select ..." DATABASE_NAME > /dev/null
```

or you may redirect into the file to look result later (this is much faster than print output into console):

```
$ mysql -uUSER -pPASSWORD -e"select ..." DATABASE_NAME > ./output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want a pager ?

run the following (in the MySQL console)

```
pager less
```

Which will use less and only show the first "screen" of info